# Is it possible to change an already assigned bytes32 variable?

Tags: bytes32

If I assign a bytes32 variable such as

```
bytes32 x = 0xffff;
```

but then I want to change the last byte (or any byte really) so that `x` is now `0xffaa`, is there any possible way to do this?  I want the change to be persistent so that any changes in `x` are reflected in the blockchain, not just mask into a particular byte and use the result.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

The following code makes `x` a storage (state) variable of the contract, which can be changed by invoking the `changeX` function.  `x` is a storage variable whose value will be persisted.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract C {
    bytes32 public x = 0xffff;

    function changeX() external {
        x = 0xffaa;
    }
}
```

You can try the code in [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.js&optimize=undefined&gist=c8937de1d4e2afbfd36a1255377700a3).

(`public` makes it easier for you to inspect the value of `x`.)

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question, but I'd like to pass a byte and the position of that byte into the function `changeX()` in your example.  How might that be done?

Comment: Please ask a new question.  (I think someone else will be able to answer faster than me.)

Comment: This example does not compile

Comment: What doesn't compile? https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.js&optimize=undefined&gist=c8937de1d4e2afbfd36a1255377700a3